# Can I expect WYSIWYG for SVG-PDFs embedded as images in LaTeX?

Tags: xetex, pdf, svg, embedding

I embed a lot of scalable illustrations by creating them in Inkscape as SVG, then exporting them to PDF and finally including that PDF in (Xe)LaTeX.

Given I am happy with the illustration-PDF individually and the final LaTeX-PDF in my PDF-viewer on my PC, can I assume that it will be rendered properly on someone else's PC/PDF-viewers? Are there pitfalls like not embedded missing system fonts used for text in the SVG or unsupported SVG features (like advanced filters) where I might not notice that something is missing?

Comment: you should always assume that there *may* be problems if there are unembedded fonts.  not everyone has the same selection of "common system fonts".  and if you are submitting for publication, you can almost always be assured that there *will* be problems with unembedded fonts.  (if your document is handled by a careful publisher, their staff will post-process to embed the necessary fonts, but be sure that you provide them with an accurate copy that they can check against.)

Comment: Note that it may not print correctly even if it displays correctly and even if all fonts are embedded ....